# Manhua about guy who gets stronger by putting rings on demonesses

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is about this guy who no lifes a game were you can max out the affinity with all the goddesses. He does so in order to have them forge special marriage rings that he uses to court and marry/capture all the demonesses which are said to be impossible to court in the game.

After doing so he talks about how hard it was to capture the demon lord and goes to sleep only to wake up right in front of the demon lord in the game. After she tries to kill him but fails he noticed that she can't hurt him because of the maxed out affinity bar and that he still has his inventory of stuff from the game including the rings that once he puts on the fingers of the demonesses he can copy their powers so he sets out on  mission to try and put all the rings on the demonesses, all the while the goddess notices that he has returned and starts to hunt him down in the world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character or place names, or any details of the art?

Comment: "My Harem Is Entirely Female Demon Villains"

Comment: Crossposted to https://www.reddit.com/r/TheGamer/comments/vqimtm/help_find_title_of_manhua_please/ FWIW

Answer (score 1):

Since Valorum declined to post an answer, [*My Harem Consists Entirely of Female Demon Villains*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-harem-consists-entirely-of-female-demon-villains)

[image: Front cover of My Harem Consists Entirely of Female Demon Villains]

> I, the earthling "hero" of this story, crossed over into another world based on a video game and suddenly appeared in a villainous female demon's bed when I arrived. If not for the fact that I had married all the villains in the game before crossing over, I'd have been killed pretty quickly. Now, the villains keep pestering me, asking me to help them rule the world, and vying for my hand in marriage. What am I supposed to do? I'll await your answers online! It's urgent!

I ran into it with a search for `manhua goddesses demons "marriage rings"`, which led me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ecchiManhua/comments/uurykn/recommendation_haremromancecomedyactionadventure/) with the following summary:

> Wuchen, the pro gamer, was the only person to complete the new VR game. His strategy was simple he increased his favorability with the goddesses to the so so level and then asked them to forge him god tier rings which he would then use to subdue the demons by utilizing the marriage feature inbuilt into the game. The marriage feature was one special attraction of the game that allowed the married partners to share each other's attributes. In the game world the demonesses were far more stronger than the goddesses, and so Wuchen thought of subduing them first. With his amazing flattery he won the favorability of the goddesses in no time, and earned several treasures and artifacts from the goddesses especially the love potions from the Goddess of Love. Once he had acquired enough resources to subdue the Demonesses, he left for his epic journey of conquering the demon world (by marrying the demonesses). He began with Litia (the demoness of lust and the strongest of all demonesses). After subduing Litia, he eventually subdued all other demonesses and became the strongest player due to sharing of attributes with his now wives, the Demonesses. After reaching the pinnacle, he was bored and thought of subduing the Goddesses now (earlier he had only increased his favorability with the Goddesses to get the invaluable artifacts but didn't marry them). Just then he gets summoned to the game world (1000 years into the future) by the Goddess of Creation (mother of all Goddesses) to conquer the demon world once again with only his marriage rings and artifacts. But what's this all goddesses have their memories of Wuchen from the game intact, on the other hand the Demonesses no longer remember him. And all his powers are down to the rock bottom (the only feature that was preserved was the one that didn't allow marriage partners to harm each other in any way). Once the saviour of the world and everyone's idol Wuchen (or Dawn star, the name he was popular as) is now infamous as a scumbag who only played with the Goddesses feelings to earn profit.